# what versions of Fastai, torch & torchvision are compatible for cuda 10.1, python 3.7?

Tags: python, pytorch, version, fast-ai, torchvision

I have created a new environment for installing fastai, which has dependency on torch & torchvision packages.

After installation, I get: RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and torchvision were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA Version=9.2 and torchvision has CUDA Version=10.1. Please reinstall the torchvision that matches your PyTorch install.

So recommend the steps for installing compatible versions of fastai and it's depencies torch, torchvision on Cuda10.1 & python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstalled the existing incompatible versions of the packages.
2. Installed using: pip install torch==1.7.0+cu101 torchvision==0.8.1+cu101 torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
3. pip install fastai (it installed fastai version 2.1.5)